# Cannot send notification to anyone

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I'm going to be quickly.
I followed the tutorial on parse.com to implement push notification in an easy way.
It seems to work fine, but when I send a notification from the dashboard only 48 people received it.
Furthermore, iTunes Connect tells me that I have 150 downloads, so 150 people should received the push notification.
What's wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary that all of your user would get push. Here is the reason your user may not get push

**Some of your users may have chosen not to receive push when they were asked for to receive push or not by iOS.**